# Japanese letters keep showing up?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I am getting some return text and its all in Japanese text. Is there a setting somewhere that would do this?

For example

```
Procedure form1.rec...
Var
   ReCBuf:array[0..9999] of char;
begin
 button1.enabled := true;
```

If I stop it right there, and look at the array it is full of Japanese characters.

Comment: Now you know what a local variable is. It's a reference to the STACK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables are not initialized by default. Your array contains arbitrary content. You must initialize `ReCBuf` before reading from it.

Comment: FWIW, I bet that it's Chinese rather than Japanese

Comment: u say Local vars, does that mean Global vars are initialized?

Comment: @DonovanBoddy Global vars are default (i.e. zero) initialized. As are members of classes. Managed types are always default initialized.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that did solve that part but it comes back. after another step. Guess i should post another question for that.

Comment: It will be essentially the same. When you take a buffer of arbitrary bytes, and interpret it as UTF-16, it tends to look Chinese.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan well its full of #0 till i run a function from a .dll ( I got the dll from a program that was done in Japanese on delphi 4.) is it possible the dll is making the results Japanese?

Comment: The Delphi 4 program won't be using UTF-16 I guess. Your program does.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan so I just need the memopad to read in the value as UTF-8?

Comment: If the data is UTF-8 you can pull it into a byte array. Then use `TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(thatByteArray)` to convert it into a native Delphi UTF-16 string.